# How to categorize documents in sharepoint

Tags: 2013, document-library, document-set, service-application, categories

I am switching from Lotus Notes into sharepoint, but I find it hard to access the data that I want easily. I am currently using documents application on sharepoint. The only options it offers are creating or uploading a new file or folder. In my lotus notes I can access files in different ways based on some categorizations such as client, author, date modified and some other categorizations. Moreover I can even categorize them based on data and client at the same time for example. All I need to do is a single click and everything is managed by notes. 
What are your suggestions?

Comment: what version of SharePoint (2007/2010/2013) and edition (Standard/Enterprise) are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013 , microsoft server 2012 r2 enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the solution to this problem,  and I have to say sharepoint is very similar and user friendly also. In order to do the categorization you should create a new app called custom list. In this list later on you can create new columns with different properties. After doing so you can create different views and use group by option to group the data. 
For a full tutorial on this read SharePoint 2013 for dummies p(78-105).

Answer (score 0):

I too have went from Lotus Notes to SharePoint and found that creating categorized views and multiple views has helped a lot.  Not trying to bash SharePoint or Microsoft but the categorization in Notes was superior in my opinion.

Comment: I have the same opinion. I was thinking to create my own application for that , but it seems to complicated task to do.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has some very powerful features for document management - metadata, navigation, content searching (with previews), version control and more.
A few links below to get you started -

[Plan document management in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263266%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[Best practices for setting SharePoint 2010 up for document management](http://blog.concentra.co.uk/2011/09/01/best-practices-for-setting-sharepoint-2010-up-for-document-management/)

[Top 10 Best Practices for Document Libraries](http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-administration/top-10-best-practices-document-libraries)

[Overview of managed metadata in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424402%28v=office.15%29.aspx).  Using [Taxonomy hierarchy](http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2013/06/05/designing-a-managed-metadata-taxonomy/)  (categorizations) in the document metadata.

[SharePoint Document Center template](http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/post/2011/07/27/sharepoint-template-document-center.aspx) (quick way to deploy a centrally managed document library)